# Sharing a file from an android device to PC

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-sharing

I have an app that creates a file based on data entered by the user and writes it to a file, however I need that file to then be transferred to a computer via Bluetooth (the laptops I am using don't have Wi-Fi direct and internet connection cant be relied on) and I cannot figure out how to do it. I have followed the tutorials on the android developers site but I cannot seem to get it to work. Any ideas or code samples that I can try?

I have tried following the android developer tutorials for Bluetooth and sharing and neither of them addressed sending files to a non-android device, they only addressed sending data (in a non-file form) to android devices and sending data to other apps.

Comment: Edit your question with answers to the following: Which tutorials have you tried? Which Bluetooth protocol are you using?